# Exposing business classes from business library in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

So, I am working on an MVVM-based core SDK for use any time I am developing some Google Apps Script based software, called `OpenSourceSDK`. It contain core business logic, including base classes to extend. For example, the file `Models/BaseModel.gs` in it is defined to be:

```
class BaseModel { 
  static FromObject(obj) {
    let model = new this()

    return model.unmarshal(obj)
  }

  /**
   * Creates a deep-copy of this, as plain Object
   */
  marshal() {
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
  }

  /**
   * Writes the target object into this and returns this
   * @param {*} obj
   */
  unmarshal(obj) {
    return Object.assign(this, obj);
  }

}
```

I [follow the instructions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries#create_and_share_a_library) to create this library, and make sure to import it into the project that's using it. When I attempt to use it, things go sideways: I am able to access the functions, but not the classes nor the constants!! I start typing in `OpenSourceSDK.BaseModel`, and IntelliSense is like "idk what to do". I sanity test via `Logger.log(typeof OpenSourceSDK.BaseModel)`, only to get `undefined`.

This is unacceptable.

What is the most efficient way to make sure these classes (and constants) are shared from that library?

NOTE: I do *not* accept the following "solutions":

- factory method per class. Why not? Because:

  - maintenance nightmare. Imagine making any change to the constructor signature of the class. You'd have to update the factory function *on every change*!
  - extra boilerplate that is wrapper around something that is so simple.
  - what happen if we want to *extend* a base class coming from the library?
- going all function-based. That defeats the whole purpose of this project. There's a reason I am doing this MVVM, and hence OOP, style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ES6 `let`, `const`, and `class` do not add themselves to the global variable (unlike `var` and `function`).

My favorite way of exporting them on Apps Script is to assign all exported objects to `globalThis`:

```js
class BaseModel { /* [...] */ }
class AnotherType { /* [...] */ }
const ExampleConstant = 420

Object.assign(globalThis, {
  BaseModel,
  AnotherType,
  ExampleConstant,
})
```

This allows you to choose what to "export" and follows a nice enough syntax.

#### Update

You can also mimic the individual export syntax with the following function:

```js
function export_(exported) {
  const { name } = exported
  if (!name)
    throw new Error(`To export a function or a class, it needs to have a name.`)
  if (name in globalThis)
    throw new Error(`A feature with the same name already exists on globalThis.`)
  globalThis[name] = exported
  return exported
}
```

And you use it like this:

```js
export_ (class Example {
  // [...]
})
```

Unfortunately the final underscore is necessary to not clash with the keyword and the parenthesis are not my cup of tea (specially the one at the end). But I agree that this would be more maintainable as you don't need to manually update the list.

### References

- [globalThis (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis)
- [Object.assign() (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Bloody hell, turns out that you actually CAN `Object.assign(globalThis, { ...classesAndConstants })` !!

This works waay better than my hack! Now if only there was a way to automate it, to ease maintenance...

Comment: Nice catch. I've updated my answer. Also, you can simply simply call your example like this `Object.assign(globalThis, classesAndConstants)`, no need to make a copy of the object :).

Comment: The Object.assign(globalThis) is a lifesaver! Thanks for the help! Just write that after any single class declaration that you want to export: I don't see any list to maintain ... class MyClass { constructor(myValue) { this.Value = myValue; } } Object.assign(globalThis, MyClass); DONE!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it resolved, but the solution is...hacky.

So, apparently, Google Apps Script exports only what is in `globalThis` of a project: just the `function`s and `var`iables. No `class`es, no `const`ants, ...

Probably has a lot to do with how ES6 works, with its `globalThis` behavior. One can see that in action, by creating a dummy `function`, a dummy `var`iable, and a dummy `class` in their local developer console:

```
function aFunction() { return 42; }
class AClass {}
var a = 41;
```

When they log `globalThis`, they'll find some massive object with `a`, `aFunction` in it, but no `class`:

[image]

Also, it turns out that `globalThis` is immutable, so you can't hack the `class` in via some IIFE...

The only recourse is to go prepend `var [ClassName] =`  in front of every `class` that is to be made public. That would assign the `[ClassName]` to a publicly exposed `var`.

I can't wait til Google Apps Script comes up with a better way to expose classes!!